# Scala create a sparse vector

Tags: scala, matrix, encoder

This is the functionality i am trying to achieve in scala
create a list of some numbers .. say (1, 2 ,3 , 4, 5) // this represents 1 document and its features
There will be n such lists with different features.

I want to put this n lists into a matrix. So that later down the line, if I want to do operations on this matrix like matrix transpose, matrix inverse i can do it easily.

Currently I do have the lists ready, but i am not sure how to use the sparseVector and Encoder function of scala as the number of rows for this matrix would be huge (approx 1 million) and columns would be 200000. So performance is also an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a map with a default value to represent a sparse matrix:

```
val matrix = Map((0, 0) -> 1, (0, 1) -> 2, (30, 4) -> 3).withDefaultValue(0)
```

If only the rows need to be sparse, you can use something like a `Vector` of `Map[Int, Int]`s instead.

In general, though, if you care about memory or the performance of matrix operations you're going to be much better off with a library that's been designed to solve this kind of problem. I've been happy with the [Colt libraries](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) in the past, but there are a number of other options, like [Scalala](http://code.google.com/p/scalala/) and [JScience](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/package-summary.html#package_description).

Comment: Yes! do you know any functions specific to scalala for Matrix operations or for building matrices

Comment: can you give an example of scalala MAtrix?

Comment: @Guarav, the Scalala documentation gives [several examples](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/wiki/QuickStart) of how to create and manipulate dense matrices. If you need sparse matrices, you're probably far better off going straight to COLT, where the `SparseDoubleMatrix2D` is [very self-explanatory](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/SparseDoubleMatrix2D.html).